# How do i include different headers based on my OS?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, portability, multiplatform

I'm writing a portable C++ application. How do I include different headers based on the operating system its running on. Is there a way to do this in C++ or do i have to use the build system?

Comment: There, did it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: You're welcome. But *please* do this in the build system, it will make your software much better maintainable. If modules cannot be written in a platform-independent way (they often can, esp. with libraries such as Boost or Qt), then design your own abstractions over OS facilities and implement these several times.

Comment: All good answers. Sorry if I'm stating the obvious but bear in mind that it's generally a good idea to favor headers and libraries that are cross-platform. Any time the [C++ Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_standard_library) has what you need, ask yourself why you'd pick an alternative.

Comment: I'm dealing with the alsa, winmm and coreaudio libraries. I've considered using something like portaudio, but its overkill for my usecase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with preprocessor:

```
#ifdef _SUNOS
//code
#elseif _LINUX
//code
#elseif _HPUX
//code
#elseif _WIN32
//code
#else
#error OS not supported
#endif
```

Comment: Note that _WIN32 is defined both on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 9):

I would use the preprocessor directives and a cross-platform build system such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  You could do:

```
#ifdef LINUX
#include <unistd.h>
#elif defined(WINDOWS)
#include <algorithm.h>
# elif Defined(MAC_OSX)
//... etc.
#else
#error No operating system defined
#endif
```

Then add the corresponding preprocessor flag to the build, such as: `-DLINUX`.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Lately tried to do this by using the defines used by the compilers but I gave up, there are so many variations and what not. I found it easier just to use my own define, set by the build system.

Answer (score 4):

We develop on Linux (Red Hat Enterprise 5), Sun (Solaris) and Windows.  Our system is to use something like this:

```
#ifndef MSWINDOWS
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <winbase.h>
#endif
//More includes here
```